# Merge data frames and sum columns with the same name

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sum

I have a relative large number of years in each data frame, with different country names in each of them. In my reproducible example, `df2` contains country `d`, which is not present in `df1`. I could achieve my goal, shown by `df3`, using several lines of code. `df3` should be the sum of both `df1` and `df2`, conditionally to country name and year. I am sure there is an easier way, but I cannot find a solution by myself. Your help is very welcome and I thank you in advance.

```
df1 <- data.frame(country = c("a", "b", "c"), year1 = c(1, 2, 3), year2 = c(1, 2, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(country = c("a", "b", "d"), year1 = c(1, 2, 3), year2 = c(1, 2, 3))

df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "country", all = TRUE) %>%
  replace_na(list(
    year1.x = 0, year1.y = 0,
    year2.x = 0, year2.y = 0)) %>%
  mutate(
    year1 = year1.x + year1.y,
    year2 = year2.x + year2.y) %>%
  select(-c(
    year1.x, year1.y,
    year2.x, year2.y))
```

This gives my expected result, but I would need a lot of manual typing to achieve it for a large number of years.

`df3` generated with this code:

```
  country year1 year2
1       a     2     2
2       b     4     4
3       c     3     3
4       d     3     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  #mutate_if(is.numeric, tidyr::replace_na, 0) %>% #in case of having NAs
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise_all(., sum, na.rm = TRUE)
  

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# country year1 year2
# <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 a             2       2
# 2 b             4       4
# 3 c             3       3
# 4 d             3       3
```

or a base r solution

```
aggregate(. ~ country, rbind(df1, df2), sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
```

which would generate the same output.

Comment: I am having a problem with `NA` values with your `dplyr` solution. It's not taking into account the sum between `NA` and another value. Nonetheless, I understand it is working fine with the example I gave here.

Comment: @bttomio: you can address this issue by replacing NAs with 0. You could add this `mutate_if(is.numeric, tidyr::replace_na, 0)` after that append. Or you could simply add `na.rm = TRUE` in the `summarise` function.

Comment: This is a nice edit, which outputs the good results. Since the question had a `dplyr` tag, I'm accepting your answer with a small edit from my side. This edit takes into account the sum of `NA` and `NA` in both data frames. With the actual formula, it results in zero (`0`), see the comments in @Yuriy Saraykin's answer. By adding `%>%
  na_if(., 0)`, zeros are gone and `NA` is back. Thanks a lot and sorry for giving an incomplete reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

**data.table**

```
rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm =T), by = country]
   country year1 year2
1:       a     2     2
2:       b     4     4
3:       c     3     3
4:       d     3     3
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Is it possible to keep `NA` at the end, instead of replacing them by zero (`0`)?

Comment: I was happy to help. I do not understand where the results are obtained `NA`. Please show me an example. You may be looking for this `rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = country]`

Comment: Sorry for adding new stuff, my reproducible example is not perfect. I didn't expect to have `NA` in both data frames. In this case, your code transform the sum  `NA + NA` in zero (`0`).

Answer (score 1):

A very simple `base` solution:

```
df3 <- merge.data.frame(df1, df2, by = "country",all = TRUE,suffixes=c("","")
df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0
df3 <- cbind(country=df3$country,df3[,2:3]+df3[,4:5])


  country year1 year2
1       a     2     2
2       b     4     4
3       c     3     3
4       d     3     3
```