# Merge dataframes ans sum by name in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have the following dataframes :

```
df1
     V1  V2
 G18941  17
 G20092 534
 G19692  10
 G19703 260
 G16777 231
 G20045   0
 ...
```

and

```
df2
   V1  V2
 G18941   0
 G20092 179
 G19692   3
 G19703 174
 G16777 147
 G20045 111
 ...
```

and I would have this one :

```
df3
    V1  V2
1 G18941  17
2 G20092 713
3 G19692  13
4 G19703 434
5 G16777 378
6 G20045 111
```

I have tried this piece of code that I found

```
df3 <- ddply(merge(df1, df2, all.x=TRUE), 
              .(V1,V2), summarise, V2=sum(as.numeric(V2)))
```

But it creates a df3 exactly like the df2...

I have also tried this code from [Merge data frames and sum columns with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67315929/merge-data-frames-and-sum-columns-with-the-same-name) :

```
df3 <- rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = V2]
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in gsum(V1) : sum is not meaningful for factors.
```

If you know how to do it I'm interested.Thanks.

Comment: In your 2nd solution try: `by = V1`, as we are grouping by V1 and summing V2

Comment: What's wrong with `df3 <- df1; df3$V2 <- df3$V2 + df2$V2`?

Comment: @Allan this only works if there are no missing values in the V2 variable, right?

Comment: @Julian it works only if there is a 1:1 correspondence between rows in the data frames, as there is in the example.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the following code works very well :

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarise_all(., sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: You should clarify that you are using external function, e.g. `library(dplyr)` :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% rbind(df2) %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  summarise(V2 = sum(V2)) %>% 
  arrange(V2)
```

**Output**:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  V1        V2
  <chr>  <int>
1 G19692    13
2 G18941    17
3 G20045   111
4 G16777   378
5 G19703   434
6 G20092   713
```

Answer (score 0):

With `base R` - `rbind` the two datasets (`df1`, `df2`) into a single dataset, then use `aggregate` with formula notation to summarise the `sum` of 'V2' grouped by 'V1'

```
aggregate(V2 ~ V1, rbind(df1, df2), sum)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.